# Removing some of Bootstrap CSS styling

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I added the Bootstrap styling link in my page head, but it adds some extra styling to my cards that I don't want. How can I remove it without deleting the Bootstrap CSS link?

I have provided a screenshot and my code below.

#### How I want to keep it

[image]

#### How it looks when BS CSS link gets added

[image]

```js
function switchTabs() {
    document.querySelectorAll(".tab-button").forEach(link => {

        link.addEventListener("click", () => {
            const menuBar = link.parentElement;
            const tabsContainer = menuBar.parentElement;
            const tabNumber = link.dataset.forTab;
            const tabToActivate = tabsContainer.querySelector(`[data-tab="${tabNumber}"]`)



            menuBar.querySelectorAll(".tab-button").forEach(link => {

                link.classList.remove("tab-button-active");
            })

            tabsContainer.querySelectorAll(".content").forEach(tab => {
                tab.classList.remove("content-active");
            })
            link.classList.add("tab-button-active");

            tabToActivate.classList.add("content-active");
        });
    });
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    switchTabs();

    document.querySelectorAll(".content").forEach(tabsContainer => {

        document.querySelector(".horizontal-tabs .tab-button").click()
    })
});



function menuToggle() {
    const toggleMenu = document.querySelector(".menu");
    toggleMenu.classList.toggle("active");
}
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Be+Vietnam+Pro:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap");

:root {
    --c-text-primary: #282a32;
    --c-text-secondary: #686b87;
    --c-text-action: #404089;
    --c-accent-primary: #434ce8;
    --c-border-primary: #eff1f6;
    --c-background-primary: #ffffff;
    --c-background-secondary: #fdfcff;
    --c-background-tertiary: #ecf3fe;
    --c-background-quaternary: #e9ecf4;
}



body {
    line-height: 1.5;
    min-height: 100vh;
    font-family: "Be Vietnam Pro", sans-serif;
    background-color: #E5E5E5 !important;
    color: var(--c-text-primary);
}



:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

.navbar-light {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar-nav {
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar-brand {
    font-size: 45px;
    color: #A388E7 !important;
    font-weight: bolder;
    padding-top: 0.3125rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.3125rem;
    margin-right: 1rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.nav-item {
    color: #686868 !important;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;
    right: -1675px !important;
}

.nav-item a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: color .15s ease-in-out, background-color .15s ease-in-out, border-color .15s ease-in-out;
}

#alert {
    position: relative;
    right: -3px !important;
}

.action {
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    right: 30px;
}

.action .profile {
    position: relative;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.action .profile img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.action .menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 120px;
    right: -10px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background: #fff;
    width: 200px;
    box-sizing: 0 5px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-radius: 15px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;

}

.action .menu.active {
    top: 80px;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}

.action .menu::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    right: 28px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

*,
::after,
::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.action .menu h3 {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 20px 0;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #555;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}

.action .menu h3 span {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #cecece;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.action .menu ul li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 16px 0;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.action .menu ul li img {
    max-width: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.action .menu ul li:hover img {
    opacity: 1;
}

.action .menu ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #555;
    font-weight: 500;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.action .menu ul li:hover a {
    color: #9370DB;
}


.responsive-wrapper {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1280px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.button {
    font: inherit;
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 0 1em;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    line-height: 1;
    border: 2px solid var(--c-border-primary);
    color: var(--c-text-action);
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    transition: 0.15s ease;
    background-color: var(--c-background-primary);
}

.button i {
    margin-right: 0.5rem;
    font-size: 1.25em;
}

.button span {
    font-weight: 500;
}

.button:hover,
.button:focus {
    border-color: var(--c-accent-primary);
    color: var(--c-accent-primary);
}



.main {
    padding-top: 3rem;
}

.main-header {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.main-header h1 {
    font-size: 1.75rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 1.25;
}

@media (max-width: 550px) {
    .main-header h1 {
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }
}

.search {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 340px;
}

.search input {
    font: inherit;
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 0 1em 0 36px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 2px solid var(--c-border-primary);
    color: var(--c-text-action);
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    transition: 0.15s ease;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 1;
}

.search input::-moz-placeholder {
    color: var(--c-text-action);
}

.search input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: var(--c-text-action);
}

.search input::placeholder {
    color: var(--c-text-action);
}

.search input:focus,
.search input:hover {
    border-color: var(--c-accent-primary);
}

.search button {
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    left: 12px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    font-size: 1.25em;
    color: var(--c-text-action);
    padding: 0;
    height: 40px;
}

.horizontal-tabs {
    margin-top: 1.5rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
    .horizontal-tabs {
        scrollbar-width: none;
        position: relative;
    }

    .horizontal-tabs::-webkit-scrollbar {
        display: none;
    }
}

.horizontal-tabs a {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    align-items: center;
    height: 48px;
    padding: 0 0.25rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: inherit;
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.15s ease;
}

.horizontal-tabs a:hover,
.horizontal-tabs a:focus,
.horizontal-tabs a.active {
    color: var(--c-accent-primary);
    border-bottom-color: var(--c-accent-primary);
}

.horizontal-tabs a+* {
    margin-left: 1rem;
}

.content-header {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-top: 3rem;
    margin-top: -1px;
    border-top: 1px solid var(--c-border-primary);
    width: 100%;
}

.content-header-intro h2 {
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.content-header-intro p {
    color: var(--c-text-secondary);
    margin-top: 0.25rem;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
    .content-header-actions a:first-child {
        display: none;
    }
}

.content {
    border-top: 1px solid var(--c-border-primary);
    margin-top: 2rem;
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.content-active {
    display: flex !important;
}




.content-panel {
    display: none;
    max-width: 280px;
    width: 25%;
    padding: 2rem 1rem 2rem 0;
    margin-right: 3rem;
}

.content-main-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
    .content-panel {
        display: block;
    }
}

.vertical-tabs {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.vertical-tabs a {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0.75em 1em;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: var(--c-text-action);
    transition: 0.15s ease;
}

.vertical-tabs a:hover,
.vertical-tabs a:focus,
.vertical-tabs a.active {
    background-color: var(--c-background-tertiary);
    color: var(--c-accent-primary);
}

.vertical-tabs a+* {
    margin-top: 0.25rem;
}

.content-main {
    padding-top: 2rem;
    padding-bottom: 6rem;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.card-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
    -moz-column-gap: 1.5rem;
    column-gap: 1.5rem;
    row-gap: 1.5rem;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
    .card-grid {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .card-grid {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    }
}

.card {
    background-color: var(--c-background-primary);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 5px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    border-radius: 8px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.card-header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 1.5rem 1.25rem 1rem 1.25rem;
}

.card-header div {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.card-header div span {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.card-header div span img {
    max-height: 100%;
}

.card-header div h3 {
    margin-left: 0.75rem;
    font-weight: 500;
}

/*---Profile---*/

/*---Profile---*/

.toggle span {
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 24px;
    border-radius: 99em;
    background-color: var(--c-background-quaternary);
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    position: relative;
    transition: 0.15s ease;
}

.toggle span:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 3px;
    top: 3px;
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    background-color: var(--c-background-primary);
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    transition: 0.15s ease;
}

.toggle input {
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    -webkit-clip-path: inset(50%);
    clip-path: inset(50%);
    height: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 1px;
}

.toggle input:checked+span {
    background-color: var(--c-accent-primary);
}

.toggle input:checked+span:before {
    transform: translateX(calc(100% - 2px));
}

.toggle input:focus+span {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px var(--c-background-tertiary);
}

.card-body {
    padding: 1rem 1.25rem;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
}

.card-footer {
    margin-top: auto;
    padding: 1rem 1.25rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
}

.card-footer a {
    color: var(--c-text-action);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
}

.tab-button-active {
    color: var(--c-accent-primary) !important;
    border-bottom: 3px solid var(--c-accent-primary) !important;
}

html::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}

html::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: var(--c-text-primary);
    border: 4px solid var(--c-background-primary);
    border-radius: 99em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>StudioPick</title>

    <!---Bootstrap CSS--->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/settings.css">
</head>

<body>
    <!---Navbar--->
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a style="font-size: 45px; color: #A388E7;" class="navbar-brand" href="#"><strong>StudioPick</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                    data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" aria-curresnt="page" href="index.html">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item2">
                            <div class="action">
                                <div class="profile" onclick="menuToggle();">
                                    <img src="./assets/avatar.jpg" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="menu">
                                    <h3 id="profile-name"><strong>User Name</strong></h3>
                                    <p class="text-muted" id="userType"
                                        style="position: relative; top: -20px; right: -60px; font-size: 12px !important">
                                        Studio</p>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <img src="./assets/icons/user.png" /><a href="studiodash.html">Dashboard</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <img src="./assets/icons/edit.png" /><a href="editprofile.html">Edit
                                                profile</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <img src="./assets/icons/envelope.png" /><a href="#">Inbox</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <img src="./assets/icons/settings.png" /><a href="#">Setting</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><img src="./assets/icons/question.png" /><a href="#">Help</a></li>
                                        <li>
                                            <img src="./assets/icons/log-out.png" /><a href="#"
                                                onclick="signOut();">Logout</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <!---Navbar--->
    <main class="main">
        <div class="responsive-wrapper">
            <div class="main-header">
                <h1>Settings</h1>
                <div class="search">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" />
                    <button type="submit">
                        <i class="ph-magnifying-glass-bold"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="horizontal-tabs">
                <a class="tab-button" href="#" data-for-tab="1">Profile</a>
                <a class="tab-button" href="#" data-for-tab="2">My Rooms</a>
                <a class="tab-button" href="#" data-for-tab="3">Session Management</a>
                <a class="tab-button" href="#" data-for-tab="4">Payment History</a>
                <a class="tab-button" href="#" data-for-tab="5">Edit Payment</a>
            </div>

            <!---Tab 1--->
            <div class="content" data-tab="1">
                <div class="content-header">
                    <div class="content-header-intro">
                        <h2>Manage your profile</h2>
                        <p>Edit your profile information such email, username, password, etc.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content-main-wrapper">
                    <div class="content-main">
                        <h3>Legal Name</h3>
                        <p class="legalName text-muted">User's Legal Name</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!---Tab 1--->
            <!---Tab 2--->
            <div class="content" data-tab="2">
                <div class="content-header">
                    <div class="content-header-intro">
                        <h2>Manage your studio rooms</h2>
                        <p>Add, delete, and edit the room images for your studio profile.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content-header-actions">
                        <a href="#" class="button">
                            <i class="ph-faders-bold"></i>
                            <span>Filters</span>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="button">
                            <i class="ph-plus-bold"></i>
                            <span>Add a room</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content-main-wrapper">
                    <div class="content-panel">
                        <div class="vertical-tabs">
                            <a href="#" class="active">View Rooms</a>
                            <a href="#">Manage Services</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content-main">
                        <div class="card-grid">
                            <article class="card">
                                <div class="card-header">
                                    <div>
                                        <span><img src="https://assets.codepen.io/285131/zeplin.svg" /></span>
                                        <h3>Room A</h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <label class="toggle">
                                        <input type="checkbox" checked>
                                        <span></span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <p>Add room's content</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-footer">
                                    <a href="#">View integration</a>
                                </div>
                            </article>
                            <article class="card">
                                <div class="card-header">
                                    <div>
                                        <span><img src="https://assets.codepen.io/285131/github.svg" /></span>
                                        <h3>Room B</h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <label class="toggle">
                                        <input type="checkbox" checked>
                                        <span></span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <p>Add room's content</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-footer">
                                    <a href="#">View integration</a>
                                </div>
                            </article>
                            <article class="card">
                                <div class="card-header">
                                    <div>
                                        <span><img src="https://assets.codepen.io/285131/figma.svg" /></span>
                                        <h3>Room C</h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <label class="toggle">
                                        <input type="checkbox" checked>
                                        <span></span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <p>Add room's content</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-footer">
                                    <a href="#">View integration</a>
                                </div>
                            </article>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!---Tab 2--->
            <!---Tab 3--->
            <div class="content" data-tab="3">
                <div class="content-panel">
                    <div class="vertical-tabs">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content-main-wrapper">
                    <div class="content-main">
                        <div class="card-grid">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!---Tab 3--->

        </div>
    </main>
    <!-- partial -->
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/phosphor-icons'></script>
    <script src="Javascript/settings.js"></script>
    <!----More Bootstrap--->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!----More Bootstrap--->

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add other Bootstrap classes to `.card-header` which is where the `background` and `border` come from.

You can use [`bg-white`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/background/) for the white background and [`border-0`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/borders/) for no border.

```js
function switchTabs() {
  document.querySelectorAll(".tab-button").forEach(link => {

    link.addEventListener("click", () => {
      const menuBar = link.parentElement;
      const tabsContainer = menuBar.parentElement;
      const tabNumber = link.dataset.forTab;
      const tabToActivate = tabsContainer.querySelector(`[data-tab="${tabNumber}"]`)



      menuBar.querySelectorAll(".tab-button").forEach(link => {

        link.classList.remove("tab-button-active");
      })

      tabsContainer.querySelectorAll(".content").forEach(tab => {
        tab.classList.remove("content-active");
      })
      link.classList.add("tab-button-active");

      tabToActivate.classList.add("content-active");
    });
  });
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  switchTabs();

  document.querySelectorAll(".content").forEach(tabsContainer => {

    document.querySelector(".horizontal-tabs .tab-button").click()
  })
});



function menuToggle() {
  const toggleMenu = document.querySelector(".menu");
  toggleMenu.classList.toggle("active");
}
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Be+Vietnam+Pro:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap");
:root {
  --c-text-primary: #282a32;
  --c-text-secondary: #686b87;
  --c-text-action: #404089;
  --c-accent-primary: #434ce8;
  --c-border-primary: #eff1f6;
  --c-background-primary: #ffffff;
  --c-background-secondary: #fdfcff;
  --c-background-tertiary: #ecf3fe;
  --c-background-quaternary: #e9ecf4;
}

body {
  line-height: 1.5;
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-family: "Be Vietnam Pro", sans-serif;
  background-color: #E5E5E5 !important;
  color: var(--c-text-primary);
}

:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.navbar-light {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar-nav {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-size: 45px;
  color: #A388E7 !important;
  font-weight: bolder;
  padding-top: 0.3125rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.3125rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.nav-item {
  color: #686868 !important;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  right: -1675px !important;
}

.nav-item a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color .15s ease-in-out, background-color .15s ease-in-out, border-color .15s ease-in-out;
}

#alert {
  position: relative;
  right: -3px !important;
}

.action {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
}

.action .profile {
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.action .profile img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.action .menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  right: -10px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #fff;
  width: 200px;
  box-sizing: 0 5px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 15px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.action .menu.active {
  top: 80px;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.action .menu::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  right: 28px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

*,
::after,
::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.action .menu h3 {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #555;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

.action .menu h3 span {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #cecece;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.action .menu ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 16px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.action .menu ul li img {
  max-width: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.action .menu ul li:hover img {
  opacity: 1;
}

.action .menu ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #555;
  font-weight: 500;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.action .menu ul li:hover a {
  color: #9370DB;
}

.responsive-wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.button {
  font: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0 1em;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  line-height: 1;
  border: 2px solid var(--c-border-primary);
  color: var(--c-text-action);
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  transition: 0.15s ease;
  background-color: var(--c-background-primary);
}

.button i {
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}

.button span {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.button:hover,
.button:focus {
  border-color: var(--c-accent-primary);
  color: var(--c-accent-primary);
}

.main {
  padding-top: 3rem;
}

.main-header {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.main-header h1 {
  font-size: 1.75rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.25;
}

@media (max-width: 550px) {
  .main-header h1 {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
  }
}

.search {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 340px;
}

.search input {
  font: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0 1em 0 36px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 2px solid var(--c-border-primary);
  color: var(--c-text-action);
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  transition: 0.15s ease;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
}

.search input::-moz-placeholder {
  color: var(--c-text-action);
}

.search input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: var(--c-text-action);
}

.search input::placeholder {
  color: var(--c-text-action);
}

.search input:focus,
.search input:hover {
  border-color: var(--c-accent-primary);
}

.search button {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  left: 12px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 1.25em;
  color: var(--c-text-action);
  padding: 0;
  height: 40px;
}

.horizontal-tabs {
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .horizontal-tabs {
    scrollbar-width: none;
    position: relative;
  }
  .horizontal-tabs::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
  }
}

.horizontal-tabs a {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  align-items: center;
  height: 48px;
  padding: 0 0.25rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: inherit;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.15s ease;
}

.horizontal-tabs a:hover,
.horizontal-tabs a:focus,
.horizontal-tabs a.active {
  color: var(--c-accent-primary);
  border-bottom-color: var(--c-accent-primary);
}

.horizontal-tabs a+* {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.content-header {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-top: 3rem;
  margin-top: -1px;
  border-top: 1px solid var(--c-border-primary);
  width: 100%;
}

.content-header-intro h2 {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.content-header-intro p {
  color: var(--c-text-secondary);
  margin-top: 0.25rem;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .content-header-actions a:first-child {
    display: none;
  }
}

.content {
  border-top: 1px solid var(--c-border-primary);
  margin-top: 2rem;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content-active {
  display: flex !important;
}

.content-panel {
  display: none;
  max-width: 280px;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 2rem 1rem 2rem 0;
  margin-right: 3rem;
}

.content-main-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .content-panel {
    display: block;
  }
}

.vertical-tabs {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.vertical-tabs a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0.75em 1em;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: var(--c-text-action);
  transition: 0.15s ease;
}

.vertical-tabs a:hover,
.vertical-tabs a:focus,
.vertical-tabs a.active {
  background-color: var(--c-background-tertiary);
  color: var(--c-accent-primary);
}

.vertical-tabs a+* {
  margin-top: 0.25rem;
}

.content-main {
  padding-top: 2rem;
  padding-bottom: 6rem;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.card-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  -moz-column-gap: 1.5rem;
  column-gap: 1.5rem;
  row-gap: 1.5rem;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .card-grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .card-grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
}

.card {
  background-color: var(--c-background-primary);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 5px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.card-header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1.5rem 1.25rem 1rem 1.25rem;
}

.card-header div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.card-header div span {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card-header div span img {
  max-height: 100%;
}

.card-header div h3 {
  margin-left: 0.75rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}


/*---Profile---*/


/*---Profile---*/

.toggle span {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 99em;
  background-color: var(--c-background-quaternary);
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.15s ease;
}

.toggle span:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 3px;
  top: 3px;
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  background-color: var(--c-background-primary);
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  transition: 0.15s ease;
}

.toggle input {
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  -webkit-clip-path: inset(50%);
  clip-path: inset(50%);
  height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 1px;
}

.toggle input:checked+span {
  background-color: var(--c-accent-primary);
}

.toggle input:checked+span:before {
  transform: translateX(calc(100% - 2px));
}

.toggle input:focus+span {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px var(--c-background-tertiary);
}

.card-body {
  padding: 1rem 1.25rem;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}

.card-footer {
  margin-top: auto;
  padding: 1rem 1.25rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
}

.card-footer a {
  color: var(--c-text-action);
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}

.tab-button-active {
  color: var(--c-accent-primary) !important;
  border-bottom: 3px solid var(--c-accent-primary) !important;
}

html::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
}

html::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: var(--c-text-primary);
  border: 4px solid var(--c-background-primary);
  border-radius: 99em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>StudioPick</title>

  <!---Bootstrap CSS--->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/settings.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!---Navbar--->
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a style="font-size: 45px; color: #A388E7;" class="navbar-brand" href="#"><strong>StudioPick</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-curresnt="page" href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item2">
              <div class="action">
                <div class="profile" onclick="menuToggle();">
                  <img src="./assets/avatar.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="menu">
                  <h3 id="profile-name"><strong>User Name</strong></h3>
                  <p class="text-muted" id="userType" style="position: relative; top: -20px; right: -60px; font-size: 12px !important">
                    Studio</p>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <img src="./assets/icons/user.png" /><a href="studiodash.html">Dashboard</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <img src="./assets/icons/edit.png" /><a href="editprofile.html">Edit
                                                profile</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <img src="./assets/icons/envelope.png" /><a href="#">Inbox</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <img src="./assets/icons/settings.png" /><a href="#">Setting</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><img src="./assets/icons/question.png" /><a href="#">Help</a></li>
                    <li>
                      <img src="./assets/icons/log-out.png" /><a href="#" onclick="signOut();">Logout</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <!---Navbar--->
  <main class="main">
    <div class="responsive-wrapper">
      <div class="main-header">
        <h1>Settings</h1>
        <div class="search">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search" />
          <button type="submit">
                        <i class="ph-magnifying-glass-bold"></i>
                    </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="horizontal-tabs">
        <a class="tab-button" href="#" data-for-tab="1">Profile</a>
        <a class="tab-button" href="#" data-for-tab="2">My Rooms</a>
        <a class="tab-button" href="#" data-for-tab="3">Session Management</a>
        <a class="tab-button" href="#" data-for-tab="4">Payment History</a>
        <a class="tab-button" href="#" data-for-tab="5">Edit Payment</a>
      </div>

      <!---Tab 1--->
      <div class="content" data-tab="1">
        <div class="content-header">
          <div class="content-header-intro">
            <h2>Manage your profile</h2>
            <p>Edit your profile information such email, username, password, etc.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content-main-wrapper">
          <div class="content-main">
            <h3>Legal Name</h3>
            <p class="legalName text-muted">User's Legal Name</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!---Tab 1--->
      <!---Tab 2--->
      <div class="content" data-tab="2">
        <div class="content-header">
          <div class="content-header-intro">
            <h2>Manage your studio rooms</h2>
            <p>Add, delete, and edit the room images for your studio profile.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="content-header-actions">
            <a href="#" class="button">
              <i class="ph-faders-bold"></i>
              <span>Filters</span>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="button">
              <i class="ph-plus-bold"></i>
              <span>Add a room</span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content-main-wrapper">
          <div class="content-panel">
            <div class="vertical-tabs">
              <a href="#" class="active">View Rooms</a>
              <a href="#">Manage Services</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="content-main">
            <div class="card-grid">
              <article class="card">
                <div class="card-header bg-white border-0">
                  <div>
                    <span><img src="https://assets.codepen.io/285131/zeplin.svg" /></span>
                    <h3>Room A</h3>
                  </div>
                  <label class="toggle">
                                        <input type="checkbox" checked>
                                        <span></span>
                                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                  <p>Add room's content</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                  <a href="#">View integration</a>
                </div>
              </article>
              <article class="card">
                <div class="card-header bg-white border-0">
                  <div>
                    <span><img src="https://assets.codepen.io/285131/github.svg" /></span>
                    <h3>Room B</h3>
                  </div>
                  <label class="toggle">
                                        <input type="checkbox" checked>
                                        <span></span>
                                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                  <p>Add room's content</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                  <a href="#">View integration</a>
                </div>
              </article>
              <article class="card">
                <div class="card-header bg-white border-0">
                  <div>
                    <span><img src="https://assets.codepen.io/285131/figma.svg" /></span>
                    <h3>Room C</h3>
                  </div>
                  <label class="toggle">
                                        <input type="checkbox" checked>
                                        <span></span>
                                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                  <p>Add room's content</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                  <a href="#">View integration</a>
                </div>
              </article>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!---Tab 2--->
      <!---Tab 3--->
      <div class="content" data-tab="3">
        <div class="content-panel">
          <div class="vertical-tabs">

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content-main-wrapper">
          <div class="content-main">
            <div class="card-grid">

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!---Tab 3--->

    </div>
  </main>
  <!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://unpkg.com/phosphor-icons'></script>
  <script src="Javascript/settings.js"></script>
  <!----More Bootstrap--->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!----More Bootstrap--->

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1

You can override Bootstrap's styles.

```css
.card-header {
    background: white;
    border: none;
}
```

in case this doesn't work, consider using [`!important`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_important.asp)

### Solution 2

If you want to keep `.card-header`'s styles for your application but just want to change it in one place then add a custom class to your `.card-header` div and style it accordingly.

PS: CSS libraries do not always provide the desired styling or classes you want. So it's best to learn what to do in such cases.